# How do I install a new bathroom exhaust fan?

Tags: diy-vs-pro

So I need a plug like shown in the picture (what is the name of this type of plug?) Every exhaust fan I've looked at has the standard plug so perhaps there is an adapter or something? Any help would be appreciated thank you. [image]

Comment: Go to Amazon and search for "3 pin fan connector molex".   Because of the wire nuts, that is obviously not the original connector.

Comment: I would just cut the socket off and fit the type of socket you want.

Comment: In general I'd agree with the "ignore the Molex™ connector and splice directly to the wire nuts" advice, but a picture showing the wire nutted connections and another showing where in the ceiling those wires go would help a lot.